# How to set numberOfSectionsInTableView, titleForHeaderInSection using dynamic json data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I have some json data given below and I want to display it in a table where the section headers are Departments, Designing, Employees, Developing, Employees.

I used static data in  `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `titleForHeaderInSection` but I want to do it using dynamic data.

How can I do this?

```
{                                                                                                                                                                          
    "Departments":[
        {
            "name":"Designing",
            "id":"1.1",
            "Employees":[
                {
                    "name":"Ramesh",
                    "id":"1.1.1",
                    "salary":"4lakhs"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Suresh",
                    "id":"1.1.2",
                    "salary":"4lakhs"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"Developing",
            "id":"1.2",
            "Employees":[
                {
                    "name":"Ram",
                    "id":"1.2.1",
                    "salary":"4lakhs"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Sam",
                    "id":"1.2.2",
                    "salary":"4lakhs"
                }
           ]
      }
}
```

Comment: filter your json comming data and add in NSMutable arrays using Dictionary and and Key

Comment: In this what u want to display in tableview?Departments names u want to display..?

Comment: "Departments" is the 1st header section title then "Designing" is the 2nd header section title then "employees" is the 3rd header section title, then there will be 3 rows 2 rows which contain employee data.. then "developing" is the 4th header section title and viceversa... i have displayed everything successfully, but as i asked in the above question i should use dynamic data instead of static data

Comment: can anybody give me a perfect solution...?

Comment: i need some better answer......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to create a NSDictionary from the string JSON object you specified.

```
    NSDictionary *myDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:nil error:NULL];
```

Then in the table view delegate methods:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [[myDict valueForKey:@"Departments"] count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[[[myDict valueForKey:@"Departments"] objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"Employees"] count];
    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[[myDict valueForKey:@"Departments"] objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"name"];
    }
```

Or at least I would try to set them like this.

Comment: uh... wait, maybe you wanted something different, like the NAMES of the departments... let me edit my answer

Comment: @Deboroh88.. ur answer seems perfect sir.... but i am also displaying the names of the employees... in cellForRowAtIndexPath    i used     NSDictionary *dict=[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
switch (section) {
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text= [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text= [dict1 objectForKey:@"name"];
            break;

Comment: @Deboroh88.. can u reply me...?

Comment: uhm... i have some problems understanding this code... i mean, what is "dict1"? To take the name of the employee i would use "[[[[[myDict valueForKey:@"Departments"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"Employees"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];"

Comment: BUT, reading your last comment on the question, i understand that you needed something different... in that case, if you want all the headers you described (well i think some of them are useless, like "Employees"), it is to edit the entire answer. (if now i got it correctly...)

Comment: from my response it would be shown the tableview like this: header:"Designing"; row1:"Ramesh"; row2:"Suresh"; header:"Developing"; row1:"Ram"; row2:"Sam".

Comment: u r redeclaring myDict... once u redeclare a variable in a function, it will be available only in that function.... what now...?

Comment: uhm... yeah, in fact you should declare it as a class variable or something... you could then initialize it in the "viewDidLoad" method of the interface, so that you are always sure that it's been initialized before the table view is populated. In this case you should declare `NSDictionary *myDict;` in the .h file, and in the `viewDidLoad` method initializing as `myDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myString options:0 error:NULL];` where myString is the string that contains the JSON object shown before...