# From json to UiTableViewControll

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, json

My plan is to fetch a json from a webservice and display the result in a grouped tableview with sections from the json.

My json sofar:

```
{
"Building 1":[{"title":"Room 1","id":"1"},{"title":"Room 2","id":"11"},{"title":"Room 3","id":"12"}],
"Building 2":[{"title":"Room 1","id":"37"},{"title":"Room 2","id":"23"}],
"Building 3":[{"title":"Room 1","id":"9"},{"title":"Room 2","id":"3"}]
}
```

I can fetch it and write it out by

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"array contains %@",json);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But how to do the rest and show it in a tableview with section header:
Building 1
   Room 1
   Room 2
   Room 3
Building 2
   Room 1

and so on?

Comment: what have you tried? there are tones of tutorials about using UITableView/UITableViewController

Comment: I have tried:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703912/how-to-set-numberofsectionsintableview-titleforheaderinsection-using-dynamic-js but its all about valueForKey with i dont have.

Comment: I just need help to guide me in the right directions on how to proceed with this. Example of how to convert the NSDictionary to something i can use in numberOfSectionsInTableView and titleForHeaderInSection

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic prototype UITableviewcell (or static cells with required sections) and load data from array into UITableviewCells. we can load data into uitableviewcells using Tableview delegate methods.

Sample code:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
    {
        //NSLog(@"inputplayerslist count=%d",[playerPositionList count]);
        return [playerPositionList count];
    }




    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChooseAPlayer"];

        NSString *ImagName =[[appDelegate.userSelection objectForKey:@"sportValue"] stringByAppendingString:@"Player.png"];
        UIImageView *playerGraphicImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:31];
        [playerGraphicImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImagName]];

        UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        [lblName setText:[playerPositionList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        UILabel *Teams = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        [Teams setText:[playerTeamidList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        UILabel *AwayTeams = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        [AwayTeams setText:[playerOPTeamidList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        UILabel *PlayersPrice = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
        [PlayersPrice setText:[playerPriceList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
```